# Perforce ( P4 ) Moving a particular version in tree to top of the tree

Tags: version-control, perforce

Let's say I have a version of file foo.c in P4 with top of the tree version being foo.c#8.

For some reason, I would like to move foo.c#4 as foo.c#9 (essentially moving version 4 to top of the tree).

One way is to do it manually (syncing version 4, taking a copy, then sync to top of tree, edit and copy 4 and re-submit).

Is there a more elegant way to push foo.c#4 to top of the tree?

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you want to undo revisions #5 thru #head:

```
p4 undo foo.c#5,#head
p4 submit
```

Or, if you prefer, you want to undo all revisions greater than #4:

```
p4 undo "foo.c#>4"
p4 submit
```

Or if you specifically wanted to just undo #5 thru #8 even if later revisions exist:

```
p4 undo foo.c#5,#8
p4 submit
```

This last variant will require a `sync`/`resolve` conflict resolution step if there are later revisions (so you can merge in the later revisions while ignoring #5 thru #8).

If you're using a server version that's more than a few years old, you could try `p4 copy`:

```
p4 copy foo.c#4 foo.c
p4 submit
```

If you're using a server version that's even older than that, here's the most elegant way to do it via regular old `p4 sync`:

```
p4 sync foo.c#4
p4 edit foo.c
p4 sync foo.c#head
p4 resolve -ay
p4 submit
```

Note that similar to the `undo` example, you have the option when doing the `sync foo.c#head` to `sync` and `resolve -ay` an intermediate version, and then `sync` and `resolve -am` later versions if you want to construct a revision that "undoes" certain changes while preserving later ones.

Here's a way to do it with `p4 print` (fewer commands for the simple case but IMO less elegant because it doesn't scale to more complex use cases):

```
p4 edit foo.c
p4 print -o foo.c foo.c#4
p4 submit
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunatelt P4version I use doesn't seem to support 'p4 undo'. Reading the man page online, looks like your solution works, but I couldn't leverage it

Comment: How ancient of a server version are you using?  (`p4 info`, "Server version" line.)

Comment: Added a few other recipes.  `p4 undo` is by far the best option if you're on a server version that supports it, because it leaves permanent records in the metadata that distinguish this from a normal `edit` operation.